# store mysql credentials in my.cnf without host

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to store a username and password in `.my.cnf` file and set the host to none?

For example, I can successfully login to MySQL with the following command:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

followed by typing in my password.

However, using the following .my.cnf file:

```
[client]
user=username
password=mypassword
```

I receive the following error when trying to login:

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It appears as if MySQL is appending a `localhost` hostname to the user.

So, how can I configure the `.my.cnf` file to use a blank host?

I tried using `user=username@''` and `host=''` in the `.my.cnf` file to no avail.

Comment: `@hostname` is not part of the username. The server appends the name of the client to the username when lookup up the permissions.

Comment: There's no such thing as a blank hostname.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works differently when you use `-u username`. What do you see when you use `SHOW GRANTS;` after connecting like that?

Comment: SHOW GRANTS reveals the following: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.* TO 'username'@'%'`

Comment: What does `select current_user();` show?

Comment: select current_user(); shows the following: `current_user()` `username@%`

Comment: `show processlist;` shows `username` as the User and `localhost` as the Host

Comment: Got it to work! It was silly and had nothing to do with the host. The password stored in .my.cnf includes special characters, so it needed to be surrounded by single quotes. Thank you for your help, I did +1 all of the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password stored in `.my.cnf` includes special characters, so it needed to be surrounded by single quotes.